# ES6 template literal to "decompiled" array representation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Template literals, when used with tags, seem to get compiled down to an array containing the strings and the substitutions.

For example:

```
mytag `my name is ${'Anthony'}`
```

seems to get compiled down to something representing:

```
mytag.apply(null, [['my name is '], 'Anthony'])
```

My question is, how could I take `` `my name is ${'Anthony'}` `` and get the `[['my name is '], 'Anthony']` "decompiled" representation?

I've included a snippet to demonstrate the above is true.

```js
function mytag(a, ...b) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    console.log(a[i]);
    console.log(b[i]);
  }
}

mytag`hello ${'world'}, how are ${'you'}`;

mytag.apply(null, [['hello', ', how are ', ''], 'world', 'you']);
```

**Edit**

Just to clarify my overall goal.

I'd like to have the ability to pass a template literal into a tag.

Here is a slightly more complicated example,

```
const myliteral = `my  name is ${() => 'Anthony'}`;
// would "decompile" to [['my name is'], f]

mytag.apply(null, fnToGetDecompiledRep(myliteral));
```

I'm using a function in `myliteral` to demonstrate that the function does not get evaluated. You can assume `mytag` has logic to evaluate functions.

Comment: by the way, isn't `mytag.apply(null, [['hello', ', how are ', ''], 'world', 'you']);` simply `mytag(['hello', ', how are ', ''], 'world', 'you');`?

Comment: To parse an untagged template literal you need a javascript compiler (i.e. `eval`).

Comment: @georg I'm not wanting to evaluate the template literal. I want to get it's "decompiled" representation.

Comment: @anthonator: yep, and this is what the compiler does. JS is not Lisp, you have no access to the program's AST from within the program. So it's either eval or Esprima or your own JS compiler.

Comment: What specifically are you looking at that compiles it down to that? It is more complicated that your snippet. It would help, are you trying to clarify how to get all this without using a tag on the template?

Comment: @loganfsmyth outputting the arguments passed to a tag gave me the array representation I used in my question. Yes, I'd like to get the array representation without the use of a tag.

Comment: Then that is not possible. You can use a tag to get the array representation like you're doing, and then pass that to a different tag later, but you'd still need a tag on the original literal.

Answer (score 3):

You could just make

```
function templateValues(...args) {
    return args;
}
```

and call it as

```
console.log(templateValues `my name is ${'Anthony'}`)
console.log(templateValues `hello ${'world'}, how are ${'you'}`;
```

> I'd like to get the array representation without the use of a tag
>
> ```
> const myliteral = `my  name is ${() => 'Anthony'}`;
> // would "decompile" to [['my name is'], f]
> mytag.apply(null, fnToGetDecompiledRep(myliteral));
> ```

No, that cannot work. `myLiteral` would be assigned string value that the literal expression creates here. You cannot "decompile" it afterwards. You need to use

```
const myParts = templateValues `my  name is ${() => 'Anthony'}`;
// same as  … = [['my name is'], () => 'Anthony'];
myTag.apply(null, myParts); // or myTag(...myParts)
```

There is no way around a tag to get the template values instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```js
const mytag = (...args) => args;
console.log(mytag`my name is ${'Jason'}`);
```

Comment: You might as well use `...args` for _all_ of the arguments and just `return args;`, e.g. `const mytag = (...args) => args;`